# Measure loadtime of all pages of an application in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have in several pages, one or more ajax calls or just button-events in the code behind of the pages, and I want a central function which can register or listen to the calls/Events and calculates the load time of the page, and then save those data (page name and event name ) in the database.
Has anyone done this before? Please help.

Thanks.

**Update**

What I'm looking for is a functionality who can save data (page name, userid, application name, load time and current date time) in a database table, every time the page is visited.

Alle pages are inheriting from a basepage.
The functionality must be depend of a Boolean setting variable, true = register , false = not. That could be an appsetting in the web.config.

Every tip or trick should be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Consider a Profiler**

Have you considered using a profiler like [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) to handle this? It can be easily added to your application via a NuGet package:

```
Install-Package MiniProfiler
```

It can easily be injected into your individual pages, allowing you to see the various load times across your application (i.e. client/AJAX, server, database, etc.) either directly within the UI:

[image]

These values can also be [persisted to a database of your choosing through a provider](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet#providers) (e.g. SQL Server, Raven, etc.)

```
// Store your profiling data within a database
MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage = new SqlServerStorage(YourConnectionString);
```

I know folks here at Stack Overflow actually wrote and developed the tool and use it to help make this site run as fast as possible, so if it worked for them, it'll probably work for you.